# Eclipse Android JDI Event Dispatch

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android dev, and have a solid background in .net c# development.
The following code gives a JDI error when debugging in eclipse. This my my first post to stack overflow. Please let me know the optimal way to pose question's if I have left info out.

I'm trying to retrieve an integer array from my SQLite db using a dbhandler.

```
public void BuildScoreList()
{
    Log.i(TAG, "BuildScoreList started");
    int intBuildHole = 0;
    totalScore = 0;
    dbHandler dbh = new dbHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Integer> scoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    scoreArray = dbh.getAllGameScoresArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.size(); i++)
    {
        intBuildHole = i + 1;
        totalScore = totalScore + scoreArray.get(i);
        listItems.add("Hole# " + String.valueOf(intBuildHole) + " Strokes= " +    String.valueOf(scoreArray.get(i)));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the error during debugging happens at:
scoreArray = dbh.getAllGameScoresArray();
Here's my dbHelper method

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getAllGameScoresArray()
{

    // Select All Query
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE, null);
    ArrayList<Integer> intArrayScore = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 0;
    int indexScore = 0;
    try
    {

        c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.isAfterLast() == false)
        {
            indexScore = c.getInt(1);
            intArrayScore.add(i, indexScore);
            i++;
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        return intArrayScore;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getAllGameScores" + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: There's the LogCat view in Eclipse, check what it prints.

Comment: Best guess without the actual exception-  c.moveToFirst returns false if there are no results, but I'm not sure if isAfterLast would return false in that case, especially after calling moveToFirst.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the prompt response. The LogCat reports Tag: jdwp with error text REQ: UNSUPPORTED (cmd=6/3 dataLen=12 id=0x002ab0..The method would return null in some cases.

Comment: The program executes fine on the android emulator, but when I step through code I get the JDI error. I'd like to be able to step through my BuildScoreList method. Any explanations would be welcomed.